# Regex for domain validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have seen a similar question asked here [Jquery how to validate domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916370/jquery-how-to-validate-domain-name) but I cannot seem to get this example to work with my code.

I would basically like to perform a reg ex against an input text box, and validate via jquery to see if it matches my search criteria for a domain name. The format must be

domainname.co.uk or .com/.org/.net (no http:// or https:// and no subdomain)

My code currently :

```
if(!/([a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com|net|org|co.uk))(?:\/|$)/$("#domain").val()) {
        $('#error').html("Invalid domain name, , please correct before proceeding.");
        return false;   
}
```

Comment: Where is the `test` function?

Comment: You need to escape the `.` in `co.uk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
!/([a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com|net|org|co.uk))(?:\/|$)/$("#domain").val())
```

Should be:

```
!/([a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com|net|org|co\.uk))(?:\/|$)/.test($("#domain").val()))
//                              ^              ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Sometimes a fresh set of eyes is the simplest solution! Will accept as answer when initial lock has gone :)

Comment: @GraemeLeighfield. I know the feeling, had the same thing today with SQL, take a coffee break.

Comment: gdoron, what do i need to ammend in the regex to not allow http://www. as it doesnt seem to do that at the moment?

Comment: @GraemeLeighfield, since javascript doesn't have  negative lookbehind, I would have use `indexOf`. [Read here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)