# Domain Name validation using regex allow all domain using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a domain name validation using jquery I want to allow all domain name inside that regex validation e.g.

```
www.abcd.xxx     valid 
www.abcd.xx.xx   valid
```

What I'm trying to do is here is my code and regex :

```
$.validator.addMethod("customurl",
            function (value, element) {
                return /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-z-]+\.(?:com|co.uk)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?/.test(value);
            },
            "Invalid url format"
            );
```

what above code will do is allow only .com and .co.uk domains but I want to allow for all it could be .org, .nl, .in, co.uk, .edu etc.

Can you guys please help me out with this.

Thanks
Randheer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery how to validate domain name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916370/jquery-how-to-validate-domain-name)

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to update the regular expression:

Please try this It will help you :

```
$.validator.addMethod("customurl",
 function (value, element) {
 return /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-z-]+\.(?:com|org|nl|in|edu|co\.uk)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?/.test(value);
            },
            "Invalid url format"
            );
```

Or You can Try This :

```
if(!/([a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com|net|org|co\.uk))(?:\/|$)/.test($("#domain").val())) {
        $('#error').html("Invalid domain name, , please correct before proceeding.");
        return false;   
}
```

And we can not put any values after . because then the domain will be invalid For example www.gmail.test.test  is invalid So for that we have limited options 
And thats why we have mention all the known keys in it like .org,.net.in.edu.co etc

Comment: thanks for your answer and yes I can do that but there could be lot of domain names and we don't know the all domain names and we need to put all those there so I was just trying to do this in a simple way.

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan but that is the only solution I think So

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan Can you please vote up or mark as answer So that it can help others also